# generate sequence by indices / one-hot encoding

Tags: python, numpy

I have a sequence `s = [4,3,1,0,5]` and `num_classes = 6` and I want to generate a Numpy matrix `m` of shape `(len(s), num_classes)` where `m[i,j] = 1 if s[i] == j else 0`.

Is there such a function in Numpy, where I can pass `s` and `num_classes`?

This is also called 1-of-k or one-hot encoding.

---

`timeit` results:

```
def b():
     m = np.zeros((len(s), num_classes))
     m[np.arange(len(s)), s] = 1
     return m

In [57]: timeit.timeit(lambda: b(), number=1000)
Out[57]: 0.012787103652954102

In [61]: timeit.timeit(lambda: (np.array(s)[:,None]==np.arange(num_classes))+0, number=1000)
Out[61]: 0.018411874771118164
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want a single `1` per row, you can fancy-index using `arange(len(s))` along the first axis, and using `s` along the second:

```
s = [4,3,1,0,5]
n = len(s)
k = 6
m = np.zeros((n, k))
m[np.arange(n), s] = 1
m
=> 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])

m.nonzero()
=> (array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), array([4, 3, 1, 0, 5]))
```

This can be thought of as using index (0,4), then (1,3), then (2,1), (3,0), (4,5).

Comment: I played around with `timeit` and this seems to be the fastest solution. Thanks!

Comment: @Albert cool. It would be nice if you could add your timing results to the question, for posterity

Comment: Hello, how would you do this if multiple dummy dimensions were present? Broadcasting yields unexpected results, and nonzero discards all the zero indexes.

Comment: @user1158559 you should probably post a new question, explaining exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Figured it out halfway through writing it but not sure I like the answer. Will post a new answer now.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
(np.array(s)[:,None]==np.arange(num_classes))+0
```

Sample run -

```
In [439]: s
Out[439]: [4, 3, 1, 0, 5]

In [440]: num_classes = 9

In [441]: (np.array(s)[:,None]==np.arange(num_classes))+0
Out[441]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Brocasting still works just do

$ (labels[:,:,:,None]==np.arange(num_classes))+0

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer won't work if your one-hot encoding adds an extra dimension to a multidimensional array. Using broadcasting will give you unexpected results - https://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/Cookbook/Indexing . This solution is elegant but not very efficient.

```
labels.shape # (80, 256, 10)

def b(labels):
     onehot = np.zeros((a,b,c,num_classes), dtype=float)

     # This is the slow, dumb line:
     (onehot_i, onehot_j, onehot_k) = np.ones(labels.shape).nonzero()

     thehotone = labels[onehot_i, onehot_j, onehot_k]
     onehot[onehot_i, onehot_j, onehot_k, thehotone] = 1
     return onehot
```