# 1-of-k (one-hot) encoding in Theano

Tags: theano

I'm doing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30604907/generate-sequence-by-indices) for Numpy. `seq` is a list with indices. I.e. this implements a 1-of-k encoding (also called one-hot).

```
def 1_of_k(seq, num_classes):
  num_frames = len(seq)
  m = np.zeros((num_frames, num_classes))
  m[np.arange(num_frames), seq] = 1
  return m
```

How would I do the same thing in Theano? (Most efficient solution which also is efficient for CUDA.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a built in function to do this ([`theano.tensor.extra_ops.to_one_hot`](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/extra_ops.html#theano.tensor.extra_ops.to_one_hot)) but it is still much slower then doing it in numpy. If feasible for your task, you might be better off computing this outside Theano and passing the dense result in as an input instead of passing just the indices.

Here's some code illustrating three numpy methods, and four Theano methods. This code includes the answers provided by Albert (`numpy_1_of_k_3`/`compile_theano_1_of_k_3`) and eickenberg (`numpy_1_of_k_2`/`compile_theano_1_of_k_4`) for comparison.

It turns out the the built in Theano method (`compile_theano_1_of_k_2`) uses roughly the same code as my own attempt (`numpy_1_of_k_1`/`compile_theano_1_of_k_1`).

```
import timeit
import numpy as np
import theano
import theano.tensor as tt
import theano.tensor.extra_ops


def numpy_1_of_k_1(seq, num_classes):
    num_frames = len(seq)
    m = np.zeros((num_frames, num_classes))
    m[np.arange(num_frames), seq] = 1
    return m


def numpy_1_of_k_2(seq, num_classes):
    return seq[:, np.newaxis] == np.arange(num_classes)


def numpy_1_of_k_3(seq, num_classes):
    shape = [seq.shape[i] for i in range(seq.ndim)] + [num_classes]
    eye = np.eye(num_classes)
    return eye[seq].reshape(shape)


def compile_theano_1_of_k_1():
    seq = tt.lvector()
    num_classes = tt.lscalar()
    num_frames = seq.shape[0]
    m = tt.zeros((num_frames, num_classes))
    m = tt.set_subtensor(m[tt.arange(num_frames), seq], 1)
    return theano.function([seq, num_classes], outputs=m)


def compile_theano_1_of_k_2():
    seq = tt.lvector()
    num_classes = tt.lscalar()
    return theano.function([seq, num_classes], outputs=theano.tensor.extra_ops.to_one_hot(seq, num_classes))


def compile_theano_1_of_k_3():
    seq = tt.lvector()
    num_classes = tt.lscalar()
    shape = [seq.shape[i] for i in range(seq.ndim)] + [num_classes]
    eye = tt.eye(num_classes)
    m = eye[seq].reshape(shape)
    return theano.function([seq, num_classes], outputs=m)


def compile_theano_1_of_k_4():
    seq = tt.lvector()
    num_classes = tt.lscalar()
    one_hot = tt.eq(seq.reshape((-1, 1)), tt.arange(num_classes))
    return theano.function([seq, num_classes], outputs=one_hot)


def main(iterations):
    theano_1_of_k_1 = compile_theano_1_of_k_1()
    theano_1_of_k_2 = compile_theano_1_of_k_2()
    theano_1_of_k_3 = compile_theano_1_of_k_3()
    theano_1_of_k_4 = compile_theano_1_of_k_4()

    test_seq = np.array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2])
    test_num_classes = 4
    test_functions = [numpy_1_of_k_1, numpy_1_of_k_2, numpy_1_of_k_3, theano_1_of_k_1, theano_1_of_k_2, theano_1_of_k_3,
                      theano_1_of_k_4]
    test_results = [test_function(test_seq, test_num_classes) for test_function in test_functions]

    for a, b in zip(test_results[:-1], test_results[1:]):
        assert np.all(np.equal(a, b)), (a, b)

    data = []
    for _ in xrange(iterations):
        num_classes = np.random.randint(100) + 1
        seq = np.random.randint(num_classes, size=(np.random.randint(100) + 1))
        data.append((seq, num_classes))

    for test_function in test_functions:
        start = timeit.default_timer()
        total = 0
        for seq, num_classes in data:
            total += test_function(seq, num_classes).sum()
        print timeit.default_timer() - start, total


main(100000)
```

Using a laptop and running the Theano code on CPU, I get the following timings in seconds:

```
numpy_1_of_k_1    1.0645
numpy_1_of_k_2    1.4018
numpy_1_of_k_3    1.6131
theano_1_of_k_1   6.3542
theano_1_of_k_2   6.4628
theano_1_of_k_3   6.5637
theano_1_of_k_4   5.4588
```

So in numpy, the identity approach is slower than the simple broadcast which is slower than the set from zeros. In Theano however the relative performance order differs; here the simple broadcast approach is fastest.

These are quite small test cases so the relative performances may differ which much larger matrices, or when running on GPU.

Comment: For `compile_theano_1_of_k_1`, I get the error `TypeError: index must be integers`.

Comment: Did you use the code verbatim? You must use an integer typed variable, e.g. `tt.lvector` in the code I posted.

Comment: Ah yes, I guess it was a seq of floats or so in my case. I also posted another solution. Not sure which is faster.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't this a simple broadcast?

```
import numpy as np
seq = np.random.randint(0, 5, 10)
one_hot = seq[:, np.newaxis] == np.arange(seq.max())  # class ids contiguous, maximum class seen (otherwise set variable n_classes)

print one_hot


import theano
import theano.tensor as T

t_seq = T.ivector()
t_one_hot = T.eq(t_seq.reshape((-1, 1)), T.arange(t_seq.max()))

f = theano.function([t_seq], [t_one_hot])

print f(seq.astype('int32'))
```

Comment: I've updated my answer with this approach included. This approach is slower under numpy but faster under Theano (for the small test cases I tried).

Comment: yeah, probably depends on dimensions of the array that is created

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
def class_idx_seq_to_1_of_k(seq, num_classes, dtype="float32"):
  shape = [seq.shape[i] for i in range(seq.ndim)] + [num_classes]
  eye = T.eye(num_classes, dtype=dtype)
  m = eye[T.cast(seq, 'int32')].reshape(shape)
  return m
```

Comment: I added this version to my performance test setup and it came out a bit slower than the built in (`set_subtensor`-based) version. Speeds in seconds using setup in my answer: numpy (1.8s), theano1 (8.6s), theano2 (8.6s), theano3 (9.2s). This answer is `theano3`.

Comment: I've updated my answer with more thorough coverage and timing analysis.